# SQL statement counts column 49 times instead of once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a SQL statement to display LinkId as index and count how many times the LinkId appeared in the table and titled that clicks and made a percent. I wanted to add the Link's URL from a different table of the same LinkId in both tables to display, but when I added an inner join it counted each LinkId 49 times. Why am I getting an output of 49 instead of 1 and how can I fix the problem?

Before InnerJoin

Input:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LinkId [Index],
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LinkId) [Clicks],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LinkId) * 100 / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1)) + '%' [Percent]
FROM
    Track_Click_7
WHERE
    CampaignId = 24896;
```

Output:

```
 Index  |  Clicks |  Percent
   26   |    1    |    50%
   37   |    1    |    50%
```

After adding inner join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Track_Click_7.LinkId [Index], 
    Campaign.Link,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Track_Click_7.LinkId) [Clicks],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Track_Click_7.LinkId) * 100 / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1)) + '%' [Percent]
FROM
    Track_Click_7
INNER JOIN 
    Campaign ON Track_Click_7.CampaignId = Campaign.CampaignId
WHERE
    Track_Click_7.CampaignId = 24896;
```

Output:

```
  Index  |  Link   | Clicks |  Percent
    26   | URL.... |   49   |    50%
    37   | URL.... |   49   |    50%
```

Desired output:

```
   Index  |  Link   | Clicks |  Percent
     26   | URL.... |    1   |    50%
     37   | URL.... |    1   |    50%
```

Comment: Try changing your join to `exists`

Comment: What is the `JOIN` trying to achieve achieve here? The reason, however, you're getting "more rows" is because you have a one to many relationship; so you are counting all the rows creating from the `JOIN`. Also, why are you converting your `COUNT` to a `varchar`? You're far better off leaving your value as a numerical data type and having the presentation layer change the formatting.

Comment: How many results do you get when you do: SELECT CampaignId, Link from Campaign where CampaignId = 24896
And what are the typical values that Link takes in the above query (in particular: can it be NULL)?

Comment: I agree with @Larnu and recommend you try a few simple queries in a new window to see how many rows there are that match the `CampaignId` in each table, then perform the `JOIN` without any of the grouping; you should see that there is duplication (49 rows) in one of the tables, which hopefully can be removed by adding to the `WHERE` clause or other such added specificity. Look through your results and see what is changing row by row - the columns that change are the ones that you should consider to add to you query to limit the results.

Comment: Why do you have multiple rows for a single `CampaignId` in a table called `campaign`?